# split a string and get the third last field from it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am running my shell script on multiple machines and all those machines can be in different datacenters.

- If machine is in `abc` datacenter, then I don't want to sleep at all and move forward to next line in the shell script.
- If machine is in `def` datacenter, then I want to sleep for 30 minutes and after that I will move to the next line in the shell script.
- If machine is in `pqr` datacenter, then I want to sleep for 60 minutes and after that I will move to the next line in the shell script.

My machine name is like this and it will be always and as you can see, datacenter name is always before `.host.com` and it will be like this only.

```
machineA.abc.host.com
machineB.def.host.com
machineC.pqr.host.com
machinef-12341.testra.abc.host.com
.....
```

In my below shell script, I already have machine name stored in `HOSTNAME` variable so how can I extract the datacenter name from that in shell script and apply above conditions? I need to extract datacenter name which is just before `.host.com` so I need to do start from at the end?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

HOSTNAME=$hostname

.....

// I want to execute this line after the above if/else if logic
echo "Hello World"
```

What is the best way to  do this? I can split the lines into variables but how to get relevant portion which I need and then apply if/elseif logic here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different solutions in a testloop:

```
hosts="machineA.abc.host.com machineB.def.host.com machineC.pqr.host.com machinef-12341.testra.abc.host.com"
for testhost in ${hosts}; do
   echo "sed ${testhost}: $(sed 's/.*\.\([^.]*\).host.com$/\1/' <<< "${testhost}")"
   echo "cut ${testhost}: $(rev <<< "${testhost}"|cut -d"." -f3 | rev)"
done
```

Comment: In my case, I am extracting hostname where the script is running so there is no hardcoded list of hosts.. so I can store the output of this into a variable and then basis on that I can do if/else if logic and sleep accordingly.

Comment: That's fine. Or use `case ${mysubstring} in ... esac`.

Comment: `rev` is a nice trick make `cut` work in this case!  Thanks @WalterA.